# Using Torque to show rises and falls?

Tags: carto, timeslider

I'm looking at a handful of different mapping projects that I'd like to do something Torque-like with, but I'd like maps to stay on the map for a limited period of time.

Some fake data:

```
Address                   Start Year         End Year
7706 Heather Limits        2002               2006
5938 Noble Shadow Inlet    2002               2003
9128 Round Pioneer Link    2003               2005
7176 Crystal Via           2004               2005
4475 Harvest Square        2004               2007
```

Think of a map of buildings participating in a rent subsidy program. One building enters the program in 1988 and exits in 2008. A dozen enter the program in 2002, and will exit in 2032. It seems like I can add points to the map based on a single date, but there's not an easy way to take them off on a specific day, too.

I'd have to turn the "cumulative" option off and then create basically a row for each site for each year that it should be on. Something like

```
TorqueYear   Address                   Start Year         End Year
2002      7706 Heather Limits        2002               2006
2002      5938 Noble Shadow Inlet    2002               2003
2003      7706 Heather Limits        2002               2006
2003      5938 Noble Shadow Inlet    2002               2003
2003      9128 Round Pioneer Link    2003               2005
2004      7706 Heather Limits        2002               2006
2004      9128 Round Pioneer Link    2003               2005
2004      7176 Crystal Via           2004               2005
2004      4475 Harvest Square        2004               2007
2005      7706 Heather Limits        2002               2006
2005      9128 Round Pioneer Link    2003               2005
2005      7176 Crystal Via           2004               2005
2005      4475 Harvest Square        2004               2007
2006      7706 Heather Limits        2002               2006
2006      4475 Harvest Square        2004               2007
2007 ...
```

Am I right about that or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your second example would work if torqueYear is type "number"